# Databricks cli authentication failed

Tags: databricks, databricks-cli

1. I executed `databricks configure --token` command and correspondingly i put my host id and token (multiple times)
2. But when i try to execute `databricks clusters list` command it gives me error: `Error: b'Bad Request'`.
   Can anyone suggest solution to this?

Comment: add `--debug` to get more information about error

Answer (score 0):

create a file: `~/.databrickscfg`

add:

```
[DEFAULT]
host = https://adb-000000000000000.azuredatatabricks.net/
token =
jobs-api-version = 2.0
```

run the command:

```
databricks clusters list
```